# AWS Express State Machine cant see input/output on the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have enabled Cloudwatch logs for the **express** state machine. I can see the executions and its events(ExecutionStarted, LambdaFunctionStarted etc) in the console, but there is no input/output details for task state in these events. Lambda functions in the state machine works as expected with input/outputs and I can see inputs in the function logs.

Whenever I created a **standard** state machine all input/outputs available in for each state in the console.

I could not find any details about this issue in the docs(besides enabling Cloudwatch logs which I enabled). Is this how **express** state machine works or additional configuration needed to see input/output values?

Comment: The Logging configuration for Step Functions includes an option to control whether execution data is included in the log events. Is it possible you have this set to false? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_CreateStateMachine.html#API_CreateStateMachine_RequestSyntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting in the CloudWatch logs configuration for Step Functions to control whether the state input and output data is included in the logged events.

You can see this in the [API Spec for CreateStateMachine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_LoggingConfiguration.html#StepFunctions-Type-LoggingConfiguration-includeExecutionData) below. The property in question is [includeExecutionData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_LoggingConfiguration.html#StepFunctions-Type-LoggingConfiguration-includeExecutionData).

```
{
   "definition": "string",
   "loggingConfiguration": { 
      "destinations": [ 
         { 
            "cloudWatchLogsLogGroup": { 
               "logGroupArn": "string"
            }
         }
      ],
      "includeExecutionData": boolean,
      "level": "string"
   },
   "name": "string",
   "roleArn": "string",
   "tags": [ 
      { 
         "key": "string",
         "value": "string"
      }
   ],
   "tracingConfiguration": { 
      "enabled": boolean
   },
   "type": "string"
}
```

This is how it would look in the console.

[image]

If you want that data to be included, you need to set that to True.